# Find value of function on cartesian product

Tags: functions

Im having trouble understanding functions in set theory, especially those which arguments are sets.

$f[(-3,2) \times  (-2,1]] = $?
and 
$f^-1[[0,\infty)]$ for $f: R^2 \rightarrow R $ where $f(x,y) =  \dfrac{y}{x^2 +1} $

Am I supposed to search for minimal and maximal value that this functions gets for cartesian product pairs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The supremum value of $f$ on $(-3, 2)\times (-2,1]$  is $\frac  15$ and the infimum  value is $-\frac 2 5$. Hence the image of the set $(-3, 2)\times (-2,1]$  is the interval $(-\frac 2 5,\frac 1 5)$. $f^{-1} [0,\infty)$ consists of all pairs $(x,y)$ such that $\frac y {1+x^{2}} \geq 0$ which is $\mathbb R \times [0, \infty)$.